# Responsive background image margin

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="house-top"></div>
<div id="vse-doma-section-2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#house-top {
  height: 976px;
  background-image: url('./img/house-top.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% auto;
}

#vse-doma-section-2 {
  height: 567px;
  background-image: url('./img/vse-doma-section-2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Both of my images have same `width: 1920px`. I just want one `div` to be under another. Also I want to remove `height` and make background image responsive but when I change width due to the height `div` looks like it has margin.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1X6s.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaSuR.png

Comment: It is happening for "background-size:100% auto;" you can try with "background-size:cover;". Because when you set "background-size:100% auto;" means no problem when your div width more than image width but when less width then image width follow the content width and height becoming less so generating gap in bottom side and seems treating line bottom margin.

Comment: invert the values use `auto 100%`

Comment: What should happen if the divs don't have the same h/w ratio as the background images? Should the background stretch, i.e. distort? Or should it be cut off at the edges?

Comment: @MrLister I expect that images will have same width and height according to the ratio. So now I have images with correct images but get   white space below.

Comment: @Hanif with cover it is not responsive - https://i.imgur.com/YJJEUfW.png

Comment: @SvetoslavDimitrov Yes, because the divs are larger than the images. Are you saying you always want the divs to be the same height as the images?

Comment: Yes it will be not possible to make responsive until your viewport until follow you image aspect ratio. You can use position "background-position:top center;"

Comment: @MrLister Yes, I need div of background-image height.

Comment: In that case, use a height of 0 for the div and a bottom-padding in %. I'm sure this has been asked before; can't seem to find a proper duplicate though.